# Passing stack allocated objects by pointer to a function which executes on another thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

As far as I know threads sharing heap memory but have their own stack.
So if I pass a stack allocated object via pointer (for polymorphic reasons) to a function which is executed on another thread, will this be safe, or will I get undefined behaviour. For example this code:

```
struct Foo{
    int counter{0};
}

void bar(Foo * obj){
    obj->counter++;
}
int main(){
   {
        Foo foo_object;
        std::thread t(bar, &foo_object);
        t.detach();
    }
    //do more stuff
}
```

Is this unsafe, because after `foo_object` goes out of scope, the pointer to `foo_object` will be invalid, but the thread could access the invalid memory?
I have a strong feeling, this is produces undefined behaviour, but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: What is the reason for not being 100% sure?

Comment: By "safe" do you mean "correct"?

Comment: yes I mean safe in the meaning of correct, I am sorry if this was't clear

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No this is not safe.  Once you get to the `}` in

```
{
    Foo foo_object();
    std::thread t(bar, &foo_object);
    t.detach();
}
```

`foo_object` will go out of scope and you will be left with a dangling pointer in the detached thread.  Since we do not know when the thread will actually start it is entirely plausible that the stack based local object will already be destroyed when you go to use it.

---

Also note that `Foo foo_object();` is a function declaration and not a local variable.  To have a variable you need `Foo foo_object;`.

Answer (score 1):

The current code is unsafe as Foo will be destroyed by the time you will access it.

If you would have C++17, I would suggest writing:

```
std::thread t([foo_object = Foo{}]{ bar(&foo_object); });
```

Though as you only have c++11, I would consider writing the following:

```
auto foo_object = std::make_shared<Foo>();
std::thread t([foo_object]{ bar(foo_object.get()); });
```

It might be miss-using shared_ptr, though it mainly works.
Another alternative is writing the following:

```
std::thread t([]{ Foo foo_object; bar(&foo_object); });
```

Comment: what does the C++17 feature do? Will it create a new object called foo_object on the new threads stack?

Comment: It will create it inside of the Lambda object.

Answer (score 0):

`foo_object` will be destroyed at the end of its scope so passing a pointer to a distinct thread is unsafe. If the separate thread attempts to dereference the dangling pointer after `foo_object` is destroyed it will invoke undefined behavior.